# Tensor () is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow and i am trying to implement a GAN by following this example  in jupyter notebook.

[Example here](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/blob/master/gan_mnist/Intro_to_GANs_Solution.ipynb)

Instead of using the MNIST data-set as used in this example i am trying to use my own data-set. I am creating an input pipeline for reading in TFRecords files and producing random batches of images. For associating objects with a randomly selected batch of images i am using this function tf.train.shuffle_batch(). But as soon i start my training and run sess.run([image_batch]) to get a random batch of images i get this error.

"ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("shuffle_batch:0", shape=(100, 4096), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.)"

Is this error because i have written my get_image() function separately?

Here is the complete code:

```
# imports 
# Paths to DIRs


IMAGE_WIDTH = 64
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 64

def get_image(files, num_classes):
 # Convert filenames to a queue for an input pipeline.
 file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
 # Create object to read TFRecords.
 reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
 # Read the full set of features for a single example.
 key, example = reader.read(file_queue)

 # Parse the example to get a dict mapping feature keys to tensors.
 # image/class/label: integer denoting the index in a classification layer.
 # image/encoded: string containing JPEG encoded image
 features = tf.parse_single_example(
    example,
    features={
        'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string,
                                            default_value='')
    })

 label = features['image/class/label']
 image_encoded = features['image/encoded']

 # Decode the JPEG.
 image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_encoded, channels=1)
 image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
 image = tf.reshape(image, [IMAGE_WIDTH*IMAGE_HEIGHT])

 # Represent the label as a one hot vector.
 label = tf.stack(tf.one_hot(label, num_classes))
 return image

labels = io.open(DEFAULT_LABEL_FILE, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()
num_classes = len(labels)

print('Processing data...')

tf_record_pattern = os.path.join(DEFAULT_TFRECORDS_DIR, '%s-*' % 'train')
train_data_files = tf.gfile.Glob(tf_record_pattern)
image = get_image(train_data_files, num_classes)

# Associate objects with a randomly selected batch of labels and images.
image_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
[image], batch_size=100,
capacity=2000,
min_after_dequeue=1000)

def model_inputs(real_dim, z_dim):
 inputs_real = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, real_dim), name='input_real') 
 inputs_z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, z_dim), name='input_z')

 return inputs_real, inputs_z

def generator(z, out_dim, n_units=128, reuse=False, alpha=0.01):
.
.
# return output

def discriminator(x, n_units=128, reuse=False, alpha=0.01):
.
.
# return output

# Size of input image to discriminator
input_size = 4096
# Size of latent vector to generator
z_size = 100
# Sizes of hidden layers in generator and discriminator
g_hidden_size = 128
d_hidden_size = 128
# Leak factor for leaky ReLU
alpha = 0.01  
# Smoothing 
smooth = 0.1

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create our input placeholders
input_real, input_z = model_inputs(input_size, z_size)

# Build the model
g_model = generator(input_z, input_size, n_units=g_hidden_size, alpha=alpha)
# g_model is the generator output

d_model_real, d_logits_real = discriminator(input_real, n_units=d_hidden_size, alpha=alpha)
d_model_fake, d_logits_fake = discriminator(g_model, reuse=True, n_units=d_hidden_size, alpha=alpha)

# Calculate losses 

# Optimizers
learning_rate = 0.002

# Get the trainable_variables, split into G and D parts
t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
g_vars = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('generator')]
d_vars = [var for var in t_vars if var.name.startswith('discriminator')]

d_train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(d_loss, var_list=d_vars)
g_train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(g_loss, var_list=g_vars)

batch_size = 100
epochs = 100
samples = []
losses = []
# Only save generator variables
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=g_vars)
with tf.Session() as sess:
 sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

 # Initialize the queue threads.
 coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
 for e in range(epochs):
    for ii in range(391510//batch_size): # training_images//batchsize
        # Get a random batch of images.
        batch = sess.run([image_batch])

        # Get images, reshape and rescale to pass to D
        batch_images = batch[0].reshape((batch_size, 4096))
        batch_images = batch_images*2 - 1
        # Sample random noise for G
        batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(batch_size, z_size))

        # Run optimizers
        _ = sess.run(d_train_opt, feed_dict={input_real: batch_images, input_z: batch_z})
        _ = sess.run(g_train_opt, feed_dict={input_z: batch_z})

    # At the end of each epoch, get the losses and print them out
    train_loss_d = sess.run(d_loss, {input_z: batch_z, input_real: batch_images})
    train_loss_g = g_loss.eval({input_z: batch_z})

# calculate accuracy
# Save training generator samples
with open('train_samples.pkl', 'wb') as f:
 pkl.dump(samples, f)

# Stop queue threads and close session.
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code, after creating the image_batch tensor, you are resetting the graph by using "tf.reset_default_graph()".

So the graph gets reset and all the tensors created before the resetting of the graph are no more elements of the new graph, because of which you are getting this error.

Create all your required tensors after resetting the graph and check. It should work.